# What do you call a cardinal $\kappa$ that is a limit of $\kappa$-many cardinals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, cardinals

For instance, $\omega$ is the limit of $\omega$-many cardinals.  But of course $\omega_1$ is not the limit of $\omega_1$-many cardinals.

1) Are there cardinals other than $\omega$ with this property? Are they easy to find and arbitrarily large?

2) If so, what do you call them?

Comment: You mean $\alpeh_0$, not $\omega$. $\omega$ is a ordinal.

Comment: Past $\omega $, these cardinals are precisely the fixed points of the aleph function, the increasing enumeration of the infinite cardinals, that is, they satisfy $\kappa=\aleph_\kappa $. They are usually referred to as fixed points.

Comment: yes ok $\aleph _0$

Comment: @Stella: It is also correct to use $\omega$ and $\omega_1$, for example, as cardinals. This is quite standard.

Comment: @AndréNicolas but $\omega_1$ is regular...

Comment: There are arbitrarily large cardinals with this property, just use that the aleph function is normal. For instance, the first fixed point past $\omega $ is the supremum of the sequence $\omega,\aleph_\omega,\aleph_{\aleph_\omega},\dots $

Comment: I read ordinal where it clearly said cardinal!

Comment: The regular fixed points are (weakly) inaccessible, but fixed points of arbitrarily large cofinality exist without the need for additional axioms.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo I think it is clear why the limit of your sequence has the property I want.  And it also shows why you can get them to be arbitrarily large.  If you want to put this in an answer and add a few more details, I will accept it.

Comment: Done. (Sorry for the delay, it took me a few days to have access to a computer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aleph function $\alpha\mapsto\aleph_\alpha$ is the increasing enumeration of the infinite cardinals. An infinite cardinal $\kappa$ has precisely $\kappa$ cardinals below iff $\kappa$ is either $\aleph_0=\omega$, or else $\kappa=\aleph_\kappa$, that is, what you are after are precisely the fixed-points of the aleph function (and that's how these cardinals are typically identified, as ``fixed points'').

Recall that a function $f\colon\mathsf{ORD}\to\mathsf{ORD}$ is *normal* iff $f$ is strictly increasing and continuous (note the last condition simply says that $f(\lambda)=\sup_{\alpha<\lambda}f(\alpha)$ for $\lambda$ limit). For any normal function there are arbitrarily large ordinals $\alpha$ such that $f(\alpha)=\alpha$: Given any $\tau$, start with $\beta_0>\tau$, and define $\beta_{n+1}=f(\beta_n)$ for all $n\in\omega$. Since $f$ is strictly increasing, we have that $\tau<\beta_0\le\beta_1\le\beta_2\le\dots$ and, letting $\beta_\omega=\sup_n\beta_n$, then continuity ensures that $f(\beta_\omega)=\beta_\omega$.

Although the ordinal $\beta_\omega$ as above is typically of cofinality $\omega$ (unless it happens that $\beta_0$ is already a fixed point of $f$, and of uncountable cofinality), it is in fact the case that $f$ admits fixed points of arbitrarily large cofinality: Simply note that continuity of $f$ ensures that the increasing enumeration of the fixed points of $f$ is also a normal function. For any limit ordinal $\tau$, it follows that the $\tau$-th such fixed point has cofinality $\mathrm{cf}(\tau)$.

The result that there are arbitrarily large fixed points (of the aleph function), of arbitrarily large cofinality, follows at once noticing that the aleph function is normal. On the other hand, we cannot quite ensure in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that there are regular fixed points, as these are precisely the (weakly) inaccessible cardinals.